# Trouble with connecting PostgreSQL in docker-compose

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a Laravel project on Docker with a PostgreSQL database locally. The structure of my project is described below:

```
nginx
   conf.d
      default.conf

php
  Dockerfile

src
  Laravel Project

docker-compose-yml
```

I can run the project successfully on the 8080 port, but I'm having trouble connecting to PostgreSQL.
Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
   laravel:

services:
   nginx:
     image: nginx:alpine
     command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
     container_name: nginx
     ports:
        - "8080:80"
     volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www
        - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
     depends_on:
       - php
     networks:
       - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

 db:
   container_name: postgres
   image: postgres
   environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_DB=expense
   volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
   ports:
      - "5446:5432"
   restart: always
   networks:
      - laravel
```

In case you want to know, here is the Dockerfile for PHP:

```
FROM php:8.0.3-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo
```

And also I want to mention the `.env` that is used by Laravel project:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=postgres
```

with this configuration first I've run the `docker-compose build` and after running the `docker-compose up` I'm getting the below result for Postgres:
[image]

And when I want to reach `127.0.0.1:5432` there's nothing to show me. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your service `db` your `POSTGRES_DB=expense` set the default database name to `expense` ([doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres))
So your .env should use `DB_DATABASE=expense` and not `postgres`

And a last thing I am not sure about (because I can't find the documentation about it) is your `DB_HOST`: I don't know if you should use the `container_name -> postgres` or the `service_name -> db`, I think it's the service_name so db in your case

Comment: I've tested your suggestion but I'm getting the same error

Comment: It seems you're using `docker-compose up` ? So you Ctrl+C to exit. You should use `docker-compose up -d` to --detach your command line